# Anyone having trouble calling Parse query in AppDelegate func handleWatchKitExtensionRequest and not getting query results

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform

Getting inconsistent results of either nil or error code:No results matched the query, when Parse code is called within the application func handleWatchKitExtRequest. (Using Apple iOS SDK 8.4 and Parse 1.7.5. ). Can someone give me some insight on how to handle this??

The same Parse code is getting proper Parse data results when called in iPhone ViewController or in the AppDelegate under func didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ( proper data results are obtained). Cannot figure out why this is happening when I put the same code into this function and it stops working???

Below is the code I am using:

Call from the Watch Extension Interface Controller:

```
var message = ["content":"runParseCode"]

        WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(message, reply: {(reply, error) -> Void in



            println(reply)



        })
```

Call from within the iPhone AppDelegate func handleWatchKitExtRequest:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleWatchKitExtensionRequest userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]?, reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void)!) {



        if let message = userInfo as? [String:String] {

            if let content = message["content"] {

                if content == "runParseCode" {



                    var query = PFQuery(className:"GameScore")



                    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("2ConDf1oj8") {

                        (gameScore:PFObject?, error:NSError?)->Void in



                        if error == nil {




                            //reply(["content":"\(gameScore)"])



                            if let score = gameScore!["score"] as? Int {

                                reply(["content":score])

                            }







                        } else {





                            let errorString = error!.userInfo!["error"] as? NSString as! String

                            reply(["content":"\(errorString)"])



                        }



                    }











                } else {



                    reply(["content":"Not proper authorization!"])



                }

            }

        }





    }
```

Comment: I'm having this exact issue — I'm using a DataManager class that I use in the iOS app and works fine, but using the same DataManager in `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest` doesn't get data.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Xcode are you using? I found that 6.4 was giving me lots of problems with that function call. I went back to Xcode 6.3 and everything works fine!